# this.$auth0.loginWithRedirect is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth0, quasar

I am following the [Auth0 quick start with Vue](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login) for my Quasar Project

**MainLayout.vue**

I have a login button `<div><button @click="login">Log in</button></div>` for this component

```js
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import EssentialLink from 'components/EssentialLink.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MainLayout',

  components: {
    EssentialLink
  },

  methods: {
    login () {
      this.$auth0.loginWithRedirect();
    }
  },

  setup () {
    const leftDrawerOpen = ref(false)

    return {
      essentialLinks: linksList,
      leftDrawerOpen,
      toggleLeftDrawer () {
        leftDrawerOpen.value = !leftDrawerOpen.value
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

**src/boot/auth0.js**

I tried to register the plugin to my [quasar bootfile (equivalent to main.js)](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files) `auth0.js`

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue'

let auth0 =  createAuth0({
    domain: "ksadhkajshds",
    client_id: "askasahsaksj",
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
})

export default boot(({ app }) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$auth0 = auth0
})

export { auth0 }
```

**quasar.config.js**

I added the bootfile to my config

```js
// code omitted
boot: [
      
      'auth0',
      'axios',
    ],
// code omitted
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the documentation indicates you should use `app.use` to register auth0 in your main.js

```
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';

const app = createApp(App);
 
app.use(
  createAuth0({
    domain: "YOUR_DOMAIN",
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin
  })
);

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: In a [discussion](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/5330/auth0-for-quasar-cordova-app) it was said there that instead of using a `main.js` one should initiate plugins via [quasar boot files](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files#usage-of-boot-files).